# Building a project with CMake including other libraries which uses different build systems

Tags: c++, c, build, cmake, unittest++

I am working on an open source project which uses `C` for libraries, `C++` for GUI and `Cmake` for managing build. This project is just started and have only couple of files. I can successfully generate `makefiles` on my linux development environment and on windows I can generate `Visual Studio` project files using CMake. All works well so far.

As the project is evolving, I am in a stage where I need a testing framework. I have good experience with `UnitTest++` which will work well on all popular platforms.

The problem is, I have no clue to integrate the `UnitTest++` build with `CMake` (they use makefile on linux and visual studio project files are available for windows). I need to build `UnitTest++` files to generate a library before my code is built. How can I specify this in CMake in a way which will work on linux and windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using this CMakeLists.txt:

```
#/**********************************************************\ 
#Original Author: Richard Bateman (taxilian)
#
#Created:    Nov 20, 2009
#License:    Dual license model; choose one of two:
#            New BSD License
#            http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php
#            - or -
#            GNU Lesser General Public License, version 2.1
#            http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html
#            
#Copyright 2009 PacketPass, Inc and the Firebreath development team
#\**********************************************************/

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

project (UnitTest++)
message ("Generating project ${PROJECT_NAME}")

include_directories (
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
  )

list (APPEND SOURCES
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/AssertException.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Test.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Checks.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/TestRunner.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/TestResults.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/TestReporter.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/TestReporterStdout.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ReportAssert.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/TestList.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/TimeConstraint.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/TestDetails.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MemoryOutStream.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/DeferredTestReporter.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/DeferredTestResult.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/XmlTestReporter.cpp
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/CurrentTest.cpp
  )

if (UNIX)
  list(APPEND SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Posix/SignalTranslator.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Posix/TimeHelpers.cpp
    )
elseif (WIN32)
  list(APPEND SOURCES
    src/Win32/TimeHelpers.cpp
    )
endif()

add_library (UnitTest++ STATIC ${SOURCES})

add_definitions(
  -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
  )

if (UNIX)
  set_target_properties(UnitTest++ PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -Wall -W -ansi"
    )
endif(UNIX)
```

Comment: Just awesome. I copied this, created a `CMakeList.txt` in the `UnitTest++` directory, and added sub directory commands to my top level cmakelist files. Everything works like a charm now. Thak you very much.

Comment: It's not nice to remove the licence info, even if `LGPL`: http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/source/browse/src/unittest-cpp/UnitTest%2B%2B/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I didn't realize it came from there, but it obviously does, so I've added the license info.